# Which is correct: negative infinity or 'does not exist'?

Tags: limits, terminology

**For the $\lim_{x\to 10^-} ln(100-x^2)$, which is more correct?**

> $\lim_{x\to 10^-} ln(100-x^2)$ = negative infinity
>
> $\lim_{x\to 10^-} ln(100-x^2)$ = DNE (Does not exist)

Graphically, $x$ approaches negative infinity, but by definition $ln(-n)$ is undefined. Does it matter whether I write the limit as negative infinity or simply non-existent?

Comment: This is only a matter of definition, nothing is more correct. There is a proper definition for limits being $\pm \infty$, just write whatever the problems asks of you. On a side note: I don't think " = DNE" is standard notation at all.

Comment: The formula $\lim \limits_{x\to 10^-} \ln(100-x^2)=-\infty$ is not an equality, it's an abbreviation of a specific meaningful formula. In this sense it's 100% correct to write it. Orally, might be a different matter.

Comment: @GitGud It can be an equality.Working in the extended real numbers is often quite useful.

Comment: It may depend on your instructor's preferences. Early on in calculus, I prefer to insist on "does not exist," in order to try to forestall nonsensical manipulations with $\pm \infty$. Later, writing $-\infty$ instead of does not exist is useful, since it is more informative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that one is *more correct* than the other. One is right, the other is wrong. To see which one is correct, rewrite the limit like this:
$$\lim_{x \to 10^-}\ln(100 - x^2) = \lim_{x \to 10^-}\ln((10 - x)(10 + x))$$
You can see clearly that, as $x \to 10^-$
$$\begin{align}
10 - x &\longrightarrow 0^+\\
10 + x &\longrightarrow 20
\end{align}$$
Therefore $(10 - x)(10 + x) \longrightarrow 0^+$ and the limit is
$$\lim_{x \to 10^-}\ln(100 - x^2) = -\infty.$$
Of course $-\infty \notin \mathbb R$, but the limit notation is purely a shorthand for a longer notation.

Comment: I don't think DNE is unambiguously wrong, as there's no standard definition for what it means.  In many calculus classes, a limit is said not to exist if there is no real limit, and positive/negative infinite limits are a subset of these.

Comment: @MartianInvader: Yes, I agree. That's why one should specify with precision how they defined a limit, in order to avoid confusion. I was assuming a definition under which a limit does not exist if the limits from the sides are different.

Answer (score 2):

It would be correct to say "does not exist in the real numbers".

It is common but incorrect to say "does not exist" when a concept is not defined.  Think about what "does not exist" actually means:

$$\lnot \exists z ~:~ z = \lim_{x \to 10^{-}} \ln(100 - x^2) \tag{A}$$

Can you prove that statement is true, using the definition of a limit?  If you use the definition of the limit in the form : "If $P(L, f, c)$, then $L = \lim_{x \to c} f(x)$" then **(A)** cannot be proven.  It is *undefined*.

If you use the definition of the limit of the form : "$P(L, f, c)$ if and only if $L = \lim_{x \to c} f(x)$" then you can prove that **(A)** is true.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way a limit can fail to exist. One of the ways a limit can fail to exist is if it decreases without bound, or if it increases without bound, or on one side it increases without bound and on the other side it decreases without bound.

Here are other limits that fail to exist, for other reasons:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \cos x$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {|x|}x$$

$$\lim_{x \to 3} \begin{cases}1 & : x \text{ is rational} \\ 0 & : x \text{ is irrational} \\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: A limit can also fail to "exist" if it is a 2D vector approaching a point, and not all paths converge to the same value.

Comment: @DanielV I was bringing limitands in $\mathbb R$, but your example is the same flavor as my second example.